# Coroutines writing to the same file

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a very simple use case:  I need to make a series of API requests against an endpoint, take the responses, do some simple transforms and then write all the responses to the same file.

The API requests are issued through Kotlin's `async` feature.  But when I try to write it to disk, the IDE correctly gives me a little hint that this is an `inappropriate blocking call`.  See below for a toy example.

What is the idiomatic way to issue these requests through `async` and write to the same file?

```
fun doAThing() {
    val file = File("...")
    file.writer().use{
        for (x in 1..4) {
            val response = async { makeHttpRequest(/*...*/) }
            it.write(transform(response)) // This is, obviously, the blocking call.
        }
    }
}
```

This particular snippet is executed from a coroutine context.

Comment: Can the requests be made in parallel? You’re using `async` for no real reason since you’re doing everything sequentially.

Comment: I absolutely can, I'm not 100% certain how to do that. I'm very new with Kotlin, and their documentation can be... opaque at times.  My understanding was that `async` is how you handle the parallelization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These async calls can be made to all be done in parallel, and then you can handle all the results at once so you'll know the writes are all done on the same thread, without even needing a single thread context. That's because all the writes would be done in a row without any suspend function calls in the middle.

```
suspend fun doAThing() {
    val responses = (1..4).map { index ->
        async { makeHttpRequest(/*...*/) }
    }.awaitAll()

    val file = File("...")
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        file.writer().use{
            for (response in responses) {
                it.write(transform(response))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to open and write to the file on a worker thread. How about this:

```
suspend fun doAThing() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    val file = File("...")
    file.writer().use{
        for (x in 1..4) {
            val response = async { makeHttpRequest(...) }
            it.write(transform(response)) // This is, obviously, the blocking call.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My only uncertainty with that, and mind you, I'm very new to kotlin, is how are writes handled in that context?  Does that Dispatchers.IO context hold a file pointer and all the coroutines know to use that, thus preventing any overwrites, or does each coroutine hold their own FP, I assume the latter, but just want to be certain.

Comment: All `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` does is suspending the caller thread as it continues with a worker thread from `Dispatchers.IO` threadpool. Writing to a file from mutiple coroutines at the same time is risky, like any other tasks that involve shared mutable states. If you're calling `doAThing` from mutliple coroutines then you should handle writes with some kind of synchronization or maybe with a dedicated thread that handles all the writes. A Channel may be a good option.